# Embedded OpenDS LDAP server with memory back-end

Tags: java, unit-testing, ldap, opends

I want to configure OpenDS LDAP server to work with memory back-end DB, for unit tests.
According to OpedDS wiki it can be done, but there is no tutorial there.

How can it be configured?

Answer (score 1):

You need the Memory backend as in "org.opends.server.backends.MemoryBackend". See the following for more information:

- [Configuration Information](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19623-01/820-6170/memory-backend.html)
- [How to embed OpenDS](https://java.net/projects/opends/pages/2_4_CreatingAnOpenDSInstanceForEmbeddedUse)